# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent while placing Call

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, notificationmanager

Whenever the call is placed on Android 13, it is causing the app to crash. I am using twilio in my react native project. Below is the sentry logs, which I am receiving.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myapp.android: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:408)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:491)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:477)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:441)
    at com.hoxfon.react.RNTwilioVoice.CallNotificationManager.createHangupNotification(CallNotificationManager.java:154)
    at com.hoxfon.react.RNTwilioVoice.TwilioVoiceModule$3.onConnected(TwilioVoiceModule.java:309)
    at com.twilio.voice.Call$1$2.run(Call.java:641)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

My android/build.gradle looks like

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        androidXCore = "1.7.0"
        // supportLibVersion = "xxx"
        playServicesVersion = "18.0.1" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.3.0"
        playCoreVersion = '1.10.3'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "20.1.0" // for google auth
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.0' // for audio palyer
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4')
        // classpath('com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2') // added for twilio
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10')
        classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1') //old 21.0.1
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion" // for audio player
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    project.ext {
        excludeAppGlideModule = true
    }
}
```

Have already tried adding these in my android/app/build.gradle but it didn't work.

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' //androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1' 
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { 
            force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
            force 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1' 
        }
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. My versions for dependencies are also mentioned below

```
 "react": "17.0.2",
 "react-native": "0.66.1",
 "react-native-twilio-programmable-voice": "github:hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice#feat/twilio-android-sdk-5",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.3.0",
 "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.3.4",
```

Comment: Does this belong to your code? `com.hoxfon.react.RNTwilioVoice.CallNotificationManager.createHangupNotification(CallNotificationManager.java:154)` ? If it does, please post that part.

Comment: It is not inside my code, but it is in the package. Please refer to this link https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/hoxfon/react/RNTwilioVoice/CallNotificationManager.java the code is there

Comment: Which piece of the stacktrace has traces of **your** code?

Comment: In react native, the code is in javascript but in the stacktrace the error is coming in java. So, basically none of my code is in stacktrace

Comment: In other words, this dependency `"react-native-twilio-programmable-voice": "github:hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice#feat/twilio-android-sdk-5"` is the source of your problem. File a bug report to the author and see what the says, maybe there's already an open issue with (hopefully) a workaround for it.

Comment: I did open an issue, but the package is not being updated actively, is there any work around like I fork it and then make the changes & use it??

Comment: uh sure, you can fork it, make a change and use it. and once you fix it, decide whether you want to push that fix to the original/master branch or not :)